# Auto create second row if element length exceeds certain value

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

So I'm trying to make it so that if there's greater than six elements, it will have half of the elements in the top and the other half on the bottom.

Currently I'm doing it like this (in Vue.js):

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <template v-if="cards.length <= 6">
            <tr>
                <td v-for="card in cards">
                    {{ card }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </template>
        <template v-else>
            <tr>
                <td v-for="card in cardsFirstHalf">
                    {{ card }}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td v-for="card in cardsSecondHalf">
                    {{ card }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </template>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to implement your requirements thru js

https://jsfiddle.net/qapf3yfL/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
<table>
    <tbody>
            <tr v-for="row in rows">
                <td v-for="card in row">
                    {{ card }}
                </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        max: 6,
        cards: ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'c7']
    },
    computed: {
        rows() {
            let cards = this.cards;
            if (cards.length <= this.max)
                return [cards]

            var mid = Math.ceil(cards.length / 2);
            return [cards.slice(0, mid), cards.slice(mid)]
        }
    }

})
```

Comment: I'm also using computed, though your answer is more concise.